# System freezing and preventing login

Tags: kernel, login

My system (Ubuntu 15.04) keeps having a problem where the machine is still up but I cannot login.  At the GUI login, the spinner just spins and at the console I get:

```
Username: dave
Password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-12-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

No mail.
```

The only way I can recover is to power off the machine.  I'm pretty sure that the disks are fine.  smartctl reports no errors.  Does anyone see anything in the log file that could be the problem?

fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
UUID=db5ef4b6-de73-499a-9094-63f64988fdfd /boot  ext2  defaults   0  2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none  swap  sw  0  0
UUID=9627f0e2-facb-473d-b1a0-807c38f3bb06 /home  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

/var/log/syslog (last stuff in log prior to power cycle):

```
May 19 18:30:25 noir kernel: [ 6713.655571] [sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated
May 19 18:30:25 noir systemd[5501]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 6814 (kill).
May 19 18:30:25 noir systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 0.
May 19 18:30:25 noir systemd[1]: Removed slice user-0.slice.
May 19 18:30:25 noir systemd[1]: Stopping user-0.slice.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152053] INFO: task kworker/7:2:601 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152058] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152061] kworker/7:2     D ffff88043ddd4580     0   601      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152071] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152074]  ffff8804254edd60 0000000000000046 ffff8804254edfd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152079]  ffff8804254edfd8 0000000000014580 ffff880425691770 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152082]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff880425691770 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152086] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152094]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152100]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152104]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152108]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152112]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152116]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152120]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152125]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152129]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152133]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152138]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152144] INFO: task kworker/2:2:1049 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152146] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152148] kworker/2:2     D ffff88043dc94580     0  1049      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152153] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152155]  ffff8804177d1d60 0000000000000046 ffff8804177d1fd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152158]  ffff8804177d1fd8 0000000000014580 ffff880424980000 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152162]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff880424980000 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152166] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152169]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152174]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152178]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152181]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152185]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152188]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152192]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152196]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152200]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152203]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152207]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152211] INFO: task polkitd:1182 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152212] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152214] polkitd         D ffff88043dd94580     0  1182      1 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152217]  ffff880416d9fdd0 0000000000000046 ffff880416d9ffd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152221]  ffff880416d9ffd8 0000000000014580 ffff880416c4c650 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152224]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff880416c4c650 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152228] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152231]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152236]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152240]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152244]  [<ffffffff810d9406>] proc_cgroup_show+0x66/0x1e0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152248]  [<ffffffff811c95ae>] seq_read+0x14e/0x390
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152253]  [<ffffffff811a6b3e>] vfs_read+0x9e/0x170
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152257]  [<ffffffff811a7669>] SyS_read+0x49/0xa0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152260]  [<ffffffff816f521d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152287] INFO: task kworker/7:3:3003 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152289] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152290] kworker/7:3     D ffff88043ddd4580     0  3003      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152295] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152296]  ffff88040f443d60 0000000000000046 ffff88040f443fd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152300]  ffff88040f443fd8 0000000000014580 ffff880422b85dc0 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152303]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff880422b85dc0 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152307] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152310]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152314]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152319]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152322]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152325]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152329]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152332]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152336]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152341]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152344]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152348]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152364] INFO: task kworker/2:0:6800 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152365] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152367] kworker/2:0     D ffff88043dc94580     0  6800      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152371] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152372]  ffff880422cb9d60 0000000000000046 ffff880422cb9fd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152376]  ffff880422cb9fd8 0000000000014580 ffff88040e4b1770 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152380]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff88040e4b1770 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152383] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152386]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152391]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152395]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152398]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152401]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152405]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152408]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152412]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152417]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152420]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152424]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152426] INFO: task kworker/7:0:6802 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152428] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152429] kworker/7:0     D ffff88043ddd4580     0  6802      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152433] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152435]  ffff880408017d60 0000000000000046 ffff880408017fd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152438]  ffff880408017fd8 0000000000014580 ffff8804078c5dc0 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152442]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff8804078c5dc0 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152446] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152449]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152453]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152457]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152460]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152464]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152467]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152470]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152474]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152479]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152482]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152486]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152488] INFO: task kworker/7:1:6803 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152490] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152491] kworker/7:1     D ffff88043ddd4580     0  6803      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152495] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152497]  ffff88041984bd60 0000000000000046 ffff88041984bfd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152500]  ffff88041984bfd8 0000000000014580 ffff8804078c4650 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152504]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff8804078c4650 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152507] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152511]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152515]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152519]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152522]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152525]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152529]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152532]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152536]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152540]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152543]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152548]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152550] INFO: task kworker/7:4:6804 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152552] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152553] kworker/7:4     D ffff88043ddd4580     0  6804      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152557] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152559]  ffff8804255b1d60 0000000000000046 ffff8804255b1fd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152562]  ffff8804255b1fd8 0000000000014580 ffff88040e751770 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152566]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff88040e751770 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152569] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152573]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152577]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152581]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152584]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152587]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152591]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152594]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152598]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152603]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152606]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152610]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152612] INFO: task kworker/7:5:6805 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152614] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152615] kworker/7:5     D ffff88043ddd4580     0  6805      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152619] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152621]  ffff88041b469d60 0000000000000046 ffff88041b469fd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152624]  ffff88041b469fd8 0000000000014580 ffff88040e752ee0 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152628]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff88040e752ee0 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152631] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152635]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152639]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152643]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152646]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152650]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152653]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152656]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152660]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152665]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152668]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152672]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152674] INFO: task kworker/7:6:6806 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152676] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152677] kworker/7:6     D ffff88043ddd4580     0  6806      2 0x00000000
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152681] Workqueue: events cgroup_offline_fn
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152683]  ffff88041b499d60 0000000000000046 ffff88041b499fd8 0000000000014580
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152686]  ffff88041b499fd8 0000000000014580 ffff88040e754650 ffffffff81c50500
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152690]  ffffffff81c50504 ffff88040e754650 00000000ffffffff ffffffff81c50508
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152693] Call Trace:
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152697]  [<ffffffff816eb4d9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152701]  [<ffffffff816e951f>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13f/0x1c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152705]  [<ffffffff816e890f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152708]  [<ffffffff810d5786>] cgroup_offline_fn+0x36/0x180
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152712]  [<ffffffff8107d05c>] process_one_work+0x17c/0x430
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152715]  [<ffffffff8107dcac>] worker_thread+0x11c/0x3c0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152718]  [<ffffffff8107db90>] ? manage_workers.isra.24+0x2a0/0x2a0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152722]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152727]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152730]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May 19 18:32:29 noir kernel: [ 6837.152734]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
May 19 18:32:54 noir kernel: [ 6862.146148] systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service stop-sigabrt timed out. Terminating.
May 19 18:32:54 noir kernel: [ 6862.146390] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service stop-sigabrt timed out. Terminating.
May 19 18:34:24 noir kernel: [ 6952.343890] systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
May 19 18:34:24 noir kernel: [ 6952.344174] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
May 20 08:41:53 noir rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="871" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Answer (score 0):

I observed this error, which you have also noted above amongst your output

Mar  4 10:13:08  kernel: [Number] sched: RT throttling activated

After this error I saw the memory use on the server ramp up greatly and it has yet to come back down, seems like a memory leak...

Comment: If it "seems", than it will be better to post a comment, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an instance of a bug in the cgroups subsystem of the Linux kernel version 3.11.x ([Bug Report](http://cgroups.vger.kernel.narkive.com/i8sXTiON/possible-regression-with-cgroups-in-3-11)) that triggers a deadlock in the kernel which leads to [soft lockup](https://linux-tips.com/t/what-is-kernel-soft-lockup/78/2). The deadlock happens when a process tries to clean up a cgroup directory. I'd recommend you to update your kernel to newer version.